# Using Django, send a Python Dictionary to a HTML Page and convert it to Javascript arrays in Javascript Script

Tags: javascript, python, django, dictionary, plot

I have been trying to send a Python Dictionary to a HTML Page and use that dictionary in Javascript to add a Graph on my website, using Django

The form takes a Image Upload, and the code is as follows,

```
 <div class=" mx-5 font-weight-bold">
    Uplaod Image
  </div>
  <input class=" " type="file" name="filePath">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
```

This image is then sent to `views.py` where it is processed and a resultant image, as well as a dictionary is generated from that image. And then again, a HTML page is rendered where the dictionary as well as the resultant image is sent in context variable. The code is as follows,

```
def predictImage(request):
    fileObj = request.FILES['filePath']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    filePathName = fs.save(fileObj.name, fileObj)
    filePathName = fs.url(filePathName)
    testimage = '.'+filePathName
    img_result, resultant_array, total_objects = detect_image(testimage)
    cv2.imwrite("media/results/" + fileObj.name, img=img_result)

    context = {'filePathName':"media/results/"+fileObj.name, 'predictedLabel': dict(resultant_array), 'total_objects': total_objects}
    #context = {}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Now, I want to convert the Dictionary items and keys into two different Javascript arrays, which are then to be used to plot a Graph on the HTML page. The template code of the Javascript is as follows,

```
          <script>
            // const value = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data_values').textContent);
            // alert(value);
            var xArray = [];
            var yArray = []; 
            
            var xArray = ["Italy", "France", "Spain", "USA", "Argentina"]; // xArray needs to have Python Dictionary's keys
            var yArray = [55, 49, 44, 24, 15]; // yArray needs to have Python Dictionary's values

            var layout = { title: "Distribution of Labels" };

            var data = [{ labels: xArray, values: yArray, hole: .5, type: "pie" }];

            Plotly.newPlot("myPlot", data, layout);
          </script>
```

I have tried a lot of different things to access my Python Dictionary in the Javascript Script and then convert that to Javascript arrays, but I still have not managed to do it. I also tried different Stackoverflow posts etc but nothing could really properly guide me on this. I am quite new to Django as well so I am not much aware of the syntax as well.

Comment: HI, did you tried to convert the dictionary into 2 arrays in python before send to frontend?

Comment: @Luiz No, but that wouldn't be an issue at all. I can do that by simply making two Python Lists and then send those Python Lists into my HTML Website, but again, the main problem is accessing those lists in Javascript. Instead of a dictionary then, I would want to know how do I access a Python List(s) in Javascript Script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From **`Django-doc`** [**`json_script`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script)

```
{{ value|json_script:"hello-data" }}
```

inside your Javascript

```
<script>    
  const data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('hello-data').textContent);
  var xArray = Object.keys(data) // return list of keys
  var yArray = Object.values(data) // return list of values
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where do I put `{{ value|json_script:"hello-data" }}` ??

Comment: Hello @AsadHussain you've to put this above and outside your script tag

Answer (score 1):

can you take a try this,

## views.py

```
# context data
context = {'filePathName':"media/results/"+fileObj.name, 'predictedLabel': dict(resultant_array), 'total_objects': total_objects,
    "data":  {"Italy":11, "France":22, "Spain":22, "USA":23, "Argentina":12}}
```

## template.html

```
  <script>
    // const data = JSON.parse();
    // alert(value);
    var data = JSON.parse("{{data|safe}}".replaceAll("'", '"'));
    var xArray = [];
    var yArray = []; 
    
    var xArray = Object.keys(data); // xArray needs to have Python Dictionary's keys
    var yArray = Object.values(data) // yArray needs to have Python Dictionary's values

    var layout = { title: "Distribution of Labels" };

    var data = [{ labels: xArray, values: yArray, hole: .5, type: "pie" }];

    Plotly.newPlot("myPlot", data, layout);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<input type="hidden" id="dictionary" value="{{ dictionary }}" />
```

JS

```
var dictionary = JSON.parse($('#dictionary').val());
```

Comment: I did this but I got an error on the line where I am parsing the `dictionary` that `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`... Not sure why :/ even though my dictionary is not empty and does contain data

Comment: can you check the value of the hidden html input in the above example by inspecting.The error you shown is due to empty dictionary

Comment: also try to pass the dictionary as ,'dictionary': json.dumps(dictionary)